# Average number of subdirs

Tags: files, directory

I have a directory which contains a number of subdirs. Each of these subdirs again contains a number of subdirs (call them subsubdirs). Now I would like to count the average number of subsubdirs in the top level directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script uses awk to extract sub-directories from the ls list. Each subdirectory is entered and it's subdirectories counted. Finally the average calculation uses dc. I've set dc (using `2 k`)  to output to 2 decimal places.

```
dirs=$(ls -ld * | awk '$1 ~ /^d.*/ { print $9 }')
ndirs=0
for d in $dirs
do
    cd $d
    current_nsubdirs=$(ls -ld * 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 ~ /^d.*/ { print $9 }' | wc -l)
    nsubdirs=$(($nsubdirs + $current_nsubdirs))
    ndirs=$(($ndirs + 1))
    cd ..
done
echo "Total subdirs $ndirs"
echo "Total subsubdirs $nsubdirs"
avg=$(dc <<< "2 k $nsubdirs $ndirs / p")
echo "Average subsubdirs $avg"
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that the directory names don't contain whitespace, unprintable characters or globbing characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can restrict a glob pattern to directories by adding a `/` at the end. Thus `*/` expands to the directories in the current directory (excluding the ones whose name begins with a dot).

Thus, assuming that no directory involved have a name beginning with `.` (if there are, you need to count them separately or configure your shell to list them as well):

```
set -- */
number_of_subdirectories=$#
set -- */*/
number_of_subsubdirectories=$#
average_number_of_subsubdirectories_per_directory=$(awk "BEGIN {print $number_of_subsubdirectories / $number_of_subdirectories; exit}")
```